# Material Dashboard Angular Theme

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular5, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-material2

I am using Angular5 and Dashboard material Angular theme.Everything working fine but the problem is that when i use binding `[(ngModel)]=fst_nme`its change the color of text box. Kindly let me know what i have to do i am really worried.Help would be appreciated

```
<div class="col-md-4">                                      
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input matInput maxlength="50" type="text" [(ngModel)]="Nom_Fst" name="Nom_Fst" placeholder="Enter First Name" />
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Comment: what is your problem ?

Comment: It should be `[(ngModel)]="fst_nme"` else the HTML doesn't compile well.

Comment: its solve my problem issue was with styling not with property coz property works fine but style got issue not i am getting problem for select option its not selection anything

Comment: ` <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                                    <select class="form-control " name="Prs_Flg" value="Prs_Flg" ngModel required>
                                                            <option value="1">Permanent Employee</option>
                                                            <option value="2">Temporary Employee</option>
                                                          </select>
                                              </mat-form-field>` this is my code